# Compilation Report Standards / Examples

Tags: annual-report

I am mandated to have a "compilation" performed for my HOA.  Is there a good example and what are the key elements and purpose of the document?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [accounting firm](http://www.lbahs.com/blog/bid/388465/Your-HOA-Audit-Review-And-Compilation-Questions-Answered):

> A compilation involves the preparation of an Association’s financial
>   statements without the CPA granting any assurance as to whether the
>   statements are reasonably stated or whether the statements are
>   prepared in accordance with Generally Accepted Accounting Standards
>   (GAAP).  In short, while the CPA will ensure the financial statements
>   are free from any obvious material error, the CPA will NOT grant any
>   assurance as to their completeness or accuracy.  A compilation is
>   unique in that an accountant need not be independent to prepare a
>   compilation and footnotes, while encouraged, are not necessary. 
>   Because of the lack of assurance granted by the CPA, and therefore the
>   lack of time incurred by the CPA in preparing the compilation, the
>   compilation is often the least expensive financial statement service
>   performed by a CPA.